# JMeter 4.0 Upload File issue in PHP Application

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

I have read so many articles on the Internet regarding Uploading Image files using JMeter but nothing worked for me. Even I have tried the approach using blazemeter plugin but no luck I'm not getting the script in jmx file.

Can someone please help me with this. The script is just passing but actually, Image is not uploading.

I would really require your inputs on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Copy the file, you want to upload into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
3. Perform upload in the browser
4. That's it, JMeter should capture the request and store it under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Point 1 is essential, if you omit it - you will neither be able to record the file upload request nor to replay it. Check out [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Dmitri T I have tried this but no luck. Could you please help me on this one.